# What's the alternative to subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, console, subprocess, python-3.9

I have a Python 3.9 script that starts another process in a *new console*. The 'other process' keeps running even after the original one has completed.

This is what I have on Windows:

```py
# startup.py script
# =================
import sys,  subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('start startup.py script')
    arguments = ['python', 'other_process.py']
    arguments.extend(sys.argv[1:])
    subprocess.Popen(
        arguments,
        creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
    )
    print('end startup.py script')
```

It works great. Below you see the original console on the left, in which I invoke `startup.py`. I also pass it a `--help` flag, which is then simply passed to the `other_process.py` script.
On the right, you see the `other_process.py` script running. Please note that the original `startup.py` script has already finished, while the `other_process.py` script is *still running*. That's exactly what I need:

[image]

The `subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` parameter doesn't work on Linux. I've heard that setting `shell=True` would have a similar effect, but it doesn't spawn a new console.

How can I get the same effect on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Unix doesn’t provide this option/service, but you can run a **terminal emulator**:

```
subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal","--"]+arguments)
```

There isn’t a standard means of finding *which* terminal emulator to use (or even which are available), unfortunately.  Checking `shutil.which` for a few common ones might be the right idea; from [Wikipedia’s list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators#Graphical), I’d recommend `gnome-terminal`, `konsole`, and `xterm`.  You still then have to deal with the slightly different syntax to run a command in each.

Comment: Thank you @Davis Herring.
I'm only a sporadic Linux user. Can you elaborate on which "common ones" you'd suggest to look for?